# Swift: Cannot assign a value of type [CombinedChartView.DrawOrder] to a value of [int]

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/
I had implement delegate: ChartViewDelegate

Code:

```
chartView.drawOrder = [CombinedChartView.DrawOrder.Bar, CombinedChartView.DrawOrder.Line]
```

but I have this error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type [CombinedChartView.DrawOrder] to a value of [int]
```

I am able to use drawOrder in Obj-C but not in Swift for the same code. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
chartView.drawOrder = 
    [
        CombinedChartView.DrawOrder.Bar.rawValue, 
        CombinedChartView.DrawOrder.Line.rawValue
    ]
```